# How it change code to see action "close submenu when other submenu open"..?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the code of my mobile responsive menu..but i am getting problem when one of the submenu open the other opened submenu not closing.
(i don't want see all submenu at once when i clicked on each but need to see only one submenu other shoud be closed)
I have solution but i don't know how to change the below code through that solution

Required Solution :http://jsfiddle.net/JqJce/6/

```
$("ul#topnav").clone().appendTo("#navmobitop");
$("ul#navnyaa").clone().appendTo("#navmobi");
$("#mobilenavtop").toggle(function() {
$(this).addClass("active");
$("#navmobitop .menuhlng").slideDown()
}, 
function() {
$(this).removeClass("active");
$("#navmobitop .menuhlng").slideUp()
});
$("#mobilenav").toggle(function() {
$(this).addClass("active");
$("#navmobi #navnyaa").slideDown()
},
function() {
$(this).removeClass("active");
$("#navmobi #navnyaa").slideUp()
});
$("#navmobi .dgnsub > a").toggle(function() {
$(this).parent().addClass("active");
$($(this).parent()).children("ul").slideDown()
}, 
function() {
$(this).parent().removeClass("active");
$($(this).parent()).children("ul").slideUp()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

change the following

```
$('.nav .nav-open').removeClass('nav-open').find('> ul  li').slideUp();
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bwwvpev9/